# Count(IIf( for Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In the detail section, `txtTCCount` contains `+1`. In the group footer section I have tried the following in an unbound box:

```
=Count(IIf([txtTCCount]=1,1,0))

=Count(IIf([txtTCCount]=1))

=Count(IIf([txtTCCount]=1,1,null))

=IIf(([txtTCCount]=1),Count([txtTCCount]),Count([null]))
```

I use a running sum over the group so that it looks like this:

```
ClientID    Count
1211        1
1211        2
1211        3
1212        1
1212        2
1222        1
1222        2
1226        1
1231        1
```

If only the `1` is counted, I should get:
`5`

If I use  `null` in the false part, nothing shows up. If I use `1`, in the false part, every line is counted instead of only the lines that contain a `1`.

I've seen this same question asked in other forums and a similar question here, and they all say it works, but I continually get incorrect results. Using version 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=Sum(IIf([txtTCCount]=1,1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it just renders zero. I may have to make a sub report if I really want this total. I wish Access could count DISTINCT values better. I will have to take another approach. Thanks again.